# yii2 url rule with named parameter of type array

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing

how can i create an url rule, with a named parameter of type array?

now i have this, working:

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'rules' => [
            'page/<id:\w+>' => 'cms/page/view',
        ],
    ],
```

to map 'page/welcome' to `module=cms`, `controller=page`, `action=view`, param `$id=welcome`

now i would like to have the url like this, with a variable number of folder-name parts:
`/page/folder1/folder2/.../folderN/pagefile`

for an action:

```
function actionPage(array $folders, string $id) {
    // expecting:
    //   $folders == [ 'folder1', 'folder2', ..., 'folderN']
    //   $id      == 'pagefile'
}
```

don't know how to write the rule. i couldn't find any documentation for the rule-syntax.

workarounds are welcome, too!

Comment: Can you try to rephrase the question, maybe break it up and concentrate on the first case you want to solve?

Comment: @dataskills: updated Q. 1. need help writing the rule. 2. if it is not possibly to do it with rules, is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the arguments passed to a controller action must be string or int because the controller action parameters work on simple GET parameters.

If you really want to pass an array of folders in a GET request it should be after the route, like: `controller/action/id?folder[]=folder1name&folder[]=folder2name`

So $id would be in scope in the controller action but you would have to "manually" go through `$_GET['folder']` to fetch the variable number of folders that are in the query string.

Comment: i saw some custom implementations of "urlRule" and was hoping to get one working with arrays. can you point me to the documentation of the urlRule syntax?

Comment: Sure, the URL Rule syntax is here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules