# regex pattern for getting array from string

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression which is able to parse a string (url):

```
/page/folder1/folder2/.../folderN/pagefile
```

into

```
[
    [1] => ['page', 'folder1', 'folder2', ..., 'folderN'],
    [2] => 'pagefile'
]
```

i wasn't able to find out, if and how subpatterns are working.
i can only use regular expressions, without any further code.
is it possible?

edit 1: I know how to do it without regular expressions. that's not the question.

edit 2: the answer to this question should help solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933317/yii2-url-rule-with-named-parameter-of-type-array)

Comment: You could use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) instead

Comment: There is no need for regular expression... Hint: split and pop

Comment: i want to write an url rule with yii, all i have got is regular expressions. of course i know how to do it by code.

Comment: Does it have to be made with only one regex, or do you accept multiple ones ?

Comment: If you still want to do it with regex, you could try these - To get all but last `[^\/]+(?=\/)` and to get last part: `[^\/]+(?=$)`

Comment: @Gawil: no, has to be one!

Comment: @e-frank: I have a solution with 4 regexes, but I should be able to make it to one with some tricks... Would you accept appending a constant string at the end of the original string BEFORE using the regex ? If the answer is no, then I don't think I can find a solution for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern:

```
([^\/]+(?=\/))|([^\/]+$)
```

[Demo/Explanation Link](https://regex101.com/r/xMWQ1b/2)

Output/Matches:

```
Match 1
    Full match  1-5 `page`
    Group 1.    1-5 `page`
Match 2
    Full match  6-13    `folder1`
    Group 1.    6-13    `folder1`
Match 3
    Full match  14-21   `folder2`
    Group 1.    14-21   `folder2`
Match 4
    Full match  22-25   `...`
    Group 1.    22-25   `...`
Match 5
    Full match  26-33   `folderN`
    Group 1.    26-33   `folderN`
Match 6
    Full match  34-42   `pagefile`
    Group 2.    34-42   `pagefile`
```

These are the matches that the regex will return, if this will not suit your use case, then the answer is NO.

Comment: @e-frank Before I bother with an fully explained answer, please tell me if this is satisfactory.

Comment: @degant this wasn't intellectual theft, this was intellectual convergence.  I was busy building the pattern and didn't see your comment.

Comment: hey @mickmackusa can completely understand that. Anyhow there aren't really a million different ways to solve this one :). Cheers!

Comment: i am looking for a regular-expression-only way. can't have php code here. that's my problem! ps: i am also accepting "NO - this is not possible" as an answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa i want to have an array ['folder1', 'folder2' ...] as result of Match 1 - so you are sure it cannot be done with regex?

Comment: @e-frank my pattern provides what your question asks for.  If this doesn't work for your yii plan, then the answer will be no.  regex can only do so much.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution with 4 regular expressions :

I know you said 1 regex, but posting the solution with multiple regexes will help understanding it.
You can do this with 4 substitutions.
1. Replace `\b\w+\b` by `'\0'`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/CuMyeT/1)
2. Replace `^\/` by `[\n\t[1] => [`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/oUiPmU/1)
3. Replace `\/` by `,`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/mukl6J/1)
4. Replace `,('\w+')$` by `],\n\t[2] => \1\n]`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ntbBNC/1) (This the final result you are looking for)

---

## Solution with 1 regular expression :

I'm warning you, it's ugly. And before you use it on your string, you need to append the following string at the end of your original string :
`'[\n\t[1] => [],\n\t[2] => ''\n]`
So you will need to do something like (I don't know which language you are using) :
`final_string = replace(original_string + "'[\n\t[1] => [],\n\t[2] => ''\n]", match_regex, replace_regex)`

So here is the regex :

```
\b(\w+)\b(?=\/[^']*('))|^\/(?=.*(\[\n\t\[1\] => \[))|\/(?=[^\/]*\/.*(,))|\/(\w+)(?=.*(],\n\t\[2\] => ')('\n\]))|'.*$
```

Replace by : `\2\1\2\3\4\6\5\7`
See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/IJDZx9/5)
Here is a commented version :

```
(?x)    # turn on free spacing mode
    \b(\w+)\b (?=    # match an entire word and capture it (group 1)
        \/    # must be followed by a / (so last word is not matched)
        [^']*    # then by a sequence of any character except '
        (')    # and then a ' which is captured into group 2
    ) |    # OR
    ^\/ (?=    # match a / at the beginning of the string
        .*    # followed by a sequence of any character
        (\[\n\t\[1\] => \[)    # followed by this specific sequence (captured into group 3)
    ) |    # OR
    \/ (?=    # match a / (not at the beginning this time)
        [^\/]*    # followed by any sequence of characters that are not /
        \/    # followed by a / (so last only last / is not matched)
        .*    # then any sequence of characters
        (,)    # then a , (captured into group 4)
    ) |    # OR
    \/(\w+) (?=    # match a word beginning with a / (capture the word into group 5)
                   # note that the only word still not matched there should be the last one
        .*    # followed by any sequence of characters
        (],\n\t\[2\] => ')    # then this specific sequence (captured into group 6)
        ('\n\])    # then this specific sequence (captured into group 7)
    ) |    # OR
    '.*$    # match everything possible (this is the previously appended string, which is erased here
            # because it is matched, and replaced by nothing
(?-x)
```

It can be optimized, but it should be enough for what you are doing...
Remember to activate the single line flag (s) to make it work (I can do it without the single line flag, but it would be even more ugly).
If you want only one regex, and cannot append anything anywhere in your string, then I won't be able to do anything more for you (I won't say it's impossible, but I think it is)

Comment: I might update the last regex sometimes with a regex a bit faster